# Gradient Descent in a 3D parameter space

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

I'm trying to computationally implement a gradient descent algorithm in 3D to find the maxima of a function. I want to use a recursion scheme like

$$\textbf{x}_{k+1} = \textbf{x}_k + \alpha \nabla f$$

The problem is that I don't know an efficient way to find the gradient of the function. And the only things I can find on the internet are either purely theoretical or applicable only to 1D cases (useless for higher dimensional spaces)

My idea was to take an initial point, and vary each of the three parameters independently by $\pm \alpha$, and then find the direction where the function increases the most. But I don't feel this is the best method. Are there any suggestions on how to approach this problem efficiently?

Comment: What sort of function are we talking about here? If it's a function which can be explicitly expressed in terms of the coordinates, you are expected to do the messy maths (differentiate the function partially w.r.t. x,y,z). I am not sure, but I think you're trying to use the random walk algorithm here.

Comment: the function can be expressed in terms of its coordinates; I have the explicit forms of the function and its first derivative.

Comment: If you have the first derivative, do the following:

**Step 1:** Initialize `x` (either randomly or using some heuristic. A good initialization is one which ensures the maxima is reached in few iterations). In your case, `x` is a _3-D vector_, corresponding to _a point in the 3-D space_.


**Step 2:** Compute the gradient at the current `x` (by feeding `x` into the derivative expression). Update `x` using the update equation (the one you wrote).

**Step 3:** Keep repeating _Step 2_ until the algorithm _converges_. The algorithm converges when _the gradients become very small_.

Comment: @JohnDoe Thanks for explaining, I understand the algorithm now.